# Как пользователю выбрать выведенные посты Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Выведены карточки с информации через цикл вордпресс   на экран и пользователю нужно выбрать пару карточек из них и нажать на кнопку "Отправить ответ" ... их надо как то в форму выводить или тип этого , чтоб пользователь мог их выбирать(отмечать галочками к примеру) и отправлять . как это реализовать? идеи нет . помогите, пожалуйста.  Просто я бы создал форму и input c label прописал бы в коде , но в вордпрессе вроде так не делают , там вроде формы создаются плагинами (contact form к примеру) , ну по крайнее мере я так делал регистрацию ,вход , обратную связь... но тут я без понятие что делать

Comment: В WP можно всё что угодно, и формы свои, в том числе. В вашем случае надо писать js-код, который по клику на карточку будет её "выбирать" (можно присваивать определённый класс), а потом по клику на кнопку "Отправить" - запускать ajax-запрос, в котором надо будет собрать выбранные карточки и отправить их id на сервер, в обработчик php.

Comment: что то типа этого ? https://api.jquery.com/change/#change-handler

Comment: там много чего "типа". Самое сложное - это ajax: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: Знаю , что самое сложное это ajax ... просто не там не там немного не понимаю, так как новичок и тут бабах такое...